# Enable schedule task using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I need to enable a schedule task through a batch file, this schedule task is set to run every 2 mins once enabled.
Using SCHTASKS  /Run    -- run the task but only once it does not care about the schedule i.e to run every 2 mins

I need to do this through a batch file. I am  using Windows 2003 server.

Please guide.

Comment: I cun't find something, so if there are any options to enable the schduled task using c# code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
schtasks /change /tn "TaskNameGoesHere" /ENABLE
```

Comment: If you read more into his question, he needs one created not an existing one altered.

Comment: I think you're wrong, he is talking about an existing task which is scheduled to run every 2 minutes. But lets wait for the op to clarify.

Comment: /ENABLE

A value that enables the scheduled task. An enabled task can run, and a disabled task cannot run.

Windows XP and Windows Server 2003:  This option is not available.

Comment: /ENABLED worked for me on windows Server 2003.  I am using /Enable and /Disable. Thanks all for help.    Yes it is an existing task and also I am SHE :-)

Comment: /ENABLED didn't work for me on WinXP, in case anyone still cares ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in Batch.  You can use schtasks /? or visit http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html.  You can get very granular with your options and there are many switches available to use.  Customize to your heart's desires.

Comment: If you are pointing to a documentation, why not use the complete and official? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Because I prefer ss64 over navigating microsoft's site?  And thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by `at` command

Example:

```
at 10AM every:SU "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
```